# SSIS get all data from A table that are not in B table and inserted it in table B

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ssis

i have two table and i need to create SSIS package "data flow task"

table A and table B, i need to create SSIS package that always insert the data that are not in table B from table A into table B (based on badgeno in A and badgeno_ID in B ). any thought and helps plz?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[A](
    [firstname] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [mobile] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [note] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [city] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [badgeno] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [lastname] [nvarchar](100) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO



CREATE TABLE [dbo].[B](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [LastName] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [DateOfBirth] [datetime] NULL,
    [FirmID] [int] NULL,
    [Phone] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Mobile] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [EMail] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [EmployeeNr] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [Note] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [PhonePrivate] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [StreetAddress] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Zip] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [City] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Data] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [UserName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Password] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ADGUID] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Language] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Theme] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [DefaultZone] [int] NULL,
    [Bed] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [badgeNO_ID] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [RegisteredBy] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Registered] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [LastUpdatedBy] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [LastUpdated] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [DefaultView] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ExpandTagList] [bit] NULL,
    [PrintEmergencyReport] [bit] NULL,
    [EmergencyReportPath] [nvarchar](255) NULL)
```

Comment: refer this to create report http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/173918/How-to-Create-your-First-SQL-Server-Integration-Se

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drag and drop an `Execute Sql Task` and put the following t-sql query in there. Jobs a gooden.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[B] 
                  ([firstname] , [mobile], [note], [City], [badgeNO_ID] , [LastName])
SELECT [A].[firstname] 
     , [A].[mobile]
     , [A].[note]
     , [A].[City]
     , [A].[badgeno] 
     , [A].[LastName]
FROM [dbo].[A] 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM [dbo].[B]
                  WHERE [dbo].[A].[badgeno] = [dbo].[B].[badgeNO_ID])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an SSIS Lookup Transformation with "No Match" Output

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141821.aspx

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/implementing-lookup-logic-in-sql-server-integration-services/

Comment: however i did this one use the un-match value, but every time i need to run the package its duplicates the outputs, my package it will always run everyday to get UN-matched values and if there is no UN-matched it shouldn't insert any values , any thoughts and ideas. @Brad D

Comment: What is your matching criteria?  is it simply on the ' Badge ID' column or another composite value?

Comment: yeah only badge ID, I DON'T WANT TO USE "INSERT INTO SELECT WHERE NOT EXIST IN THE OTHER TABLE" @BRAD D